# How to ask a user to confirm edits to a record in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a working access database that uses a multiple items form along with a search function in order to display records. I noticed that it was really easy to change information in a record without noticing.

Is there a way to ask a user if they're sure they want to make changes to a record before the table is updated?

Comment: if you're able to do something (like handle an event of when something happens) when an input or field is changed and make it pull up a pop-up that asks them to confirm the change they just made, and if they say no, then revert it back to what it was

Comment: Generally we would use the form's [BeforeUpdate Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-beforeupdate-event-access) to confirm or undo pending changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of event can be handled with a simple response on save / update event.

```
response = MsgBox("Save your record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Confirmation")
If response = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    Me.Undo
End If
```

`Cancel = True` stops the record from being written and saved.
`Me.Undo` reverts the changes to the source

This would be handled through the `BeforeUpdate` event.

Alternatively, this can be handled differently by using a specific `save` function for the form (where the form would otherwise never update the source), and simply posting a similiar confirmation where a `vbYes` results in a save.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what others have suggested and process the `BeforeUpdate` event or use an unbound form with a `Save` button. There is a third option, which is ideal for preventing accidental edits on forms that are mainly meant for data retrieval and only occasionally for data editing. Add a toggle button that toggles the form from `ReadOnly` to `ReadWrite` by means of the `AllowEdits` parameter.